# One operation after another v.s Bulk Operations in batches

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm seeking some algorithm advice. Let's say the idea is you have to do something like this:

```
operation.getAnimal('zebra')
  .then(animal => {
    return operation.doSomethingWithAnimal(animal)
  })
```

But rather than doing this one just time, you need to do this for a number of different animals.

```
let animals = ['zebra', 'dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'bird']

Promise.map(animals).then(animalName => {
  return operation.getAnimal(animalName)
    .then(animal => {
      return operation.doSomethingWithAnimal(animal)
    })
})
```

or you can do something like this:

```
function props (items, promise) {
  let results = {}
  _.each(items, item => {
    results[item] = promise(item)
  })
  return results
}

Promise.props(props(animals, option.getAnimal))
  .then(gottenAnimals => {
    return Promise.props(props(gottenAnimals, options.doSomethingWithAnimal))
  })
```

The first example will get the animal then do something, where,
The second example will get all animals then run do something with them.

Comment: Not a whole lot of difference. With the first example you should save some memory since you're not storing them all in an array before working on them.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @MikeC thats the exact kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

They are pretty similar but have different features:

2nd:

- `Promise.props`'s `then` runs only if no error occurs.
- `Promise.props` approach lets you easily (and more clearly) run code after all promise resolutions
- computationally you have O(2*N) complexity

1st:

- You obtain results even in case of errors.
- You can implement error control (or kinda retry logic for example)
- You must sync promises by yourself
- computationally you have O(N) complexity